# Grails 4 and Spring Security 4 - How to update username

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-security

I have a pretty basic Grails 4 application that uses the Spring Security plugin. I'm not understanding how to let the user change his username and then reauthenticate. In my application the username is the email address. All the security is working fine. But let's say the user wants to update his email address in my application.

Currently the user can update his password and that works fine. After the new password value is set (and of course validated, checked, matched, all that stuff) and saved, then I call

```
springSecurityService.reauthenticate user.username
```

When updating the username, however, I cannot simply change the username on the user object and then call

```
springSecurityService.reauthenticate user.username
```

because the user has not yet been authenticated with the new username so the reauthenticate method fails saying it can't find the user.

I think I'm probably missing something basic in my process flow or something and would love some direction.

Comment: they easy way to be simply to end user's session and let him login again. That's more or less standard approach which goes hand in hand with verification of newly entered email

Comment: @injecteer I love that answer. I'll consider this solved.